# Missing xtype / alias on a Controller, using in refs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I am little confused with xtype and alias on a controller. It's my controller and I never added an xtype or alias. Is one created by default? I don't seem to find it on the controller instance.

From what I believe, if I create an xtype then an alias is automatically assigned with a prefix of widget? Is this true also from alias creating and the xtype would be assigned less the widget prefix?

The reason I ask is that I am doing getController inside another controller and I wanted to know if I could assign a ref using xtype under another controller.

Is this possible? Or should I always call getController?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getController` to get a reference to another controller. There's no way to use an alias or xtype. What happens if you could set the reference of controller A on controller B and visa versa?

But...there are also other ways to call methods from another controller. This examples are untested though.

You could for example borrow methods from controller a on controller b:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.app.ControllerA', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

    requires : [
        'MyApp.app.ControllerB'
    ],

    ...

}, function(Controller) {
    Controller.borrow(MyApp.app.ControllerB, ['methodA', 'methodB', 'methodC', 'methodD']);
});
```

You can also (and I prefer this one as imo an async application should be event driven) listen to events that are fired from the controller:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.ControllerA', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    id: 'controllerAId',

    init: function() {
        var me = this;

        me.fireEvent('bar');
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.controller.ControllerB', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        var me = this;

        me.listen({
            global: {
                ...
            },
            controller: {
                '*': {
                    foobar: 'onAnyFooBar'
                },
                '#controllerAId': {
                    bar: 'onFooBar'
                }
            },
            component: {
                ...
            },
            store: {
                ...
            }
        });
    },

    onFooBar: function(controller) {
        console.log('Controller B', 'onFooBar');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go the route of listening for an event in the controller you are trying to access and you can fire it from anywhere you want. The issue with using getControlller(*App.controller.controllerName*) is that if the file isn't load it it will load it into your application which might have some negative performance issues (ie if the controller is large might take a long time to pull resource from the server etc).